# Creating multiple panda strings

Tags: python, pandas

Good morning community,

my goal is to visualise my data from my experiment I perform daily (this is, i want to plot it).

I wish to work with only one CSV, with its data and then I add, per each row, the date I performed the experiment.
The thing is that, every day, I have multiple rows of data.
In the end I wish to visualise the Data and for each Date have a different color or just a different label ( i do not know if this is actually possible, I am talking about a 20 different days).

I believe I have to create a python that parsers this CSV and then Split this CSV per each Date.

So for instance I have a csv with  this data:

| P1 | P2 | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | 2 |

So I read the csv with this command:

```
x = pd.read_csv ( 'prova.csv' , sep = ';' )
```

Then when I want to create each dataFrame I see it does not create the set of dataframe, but only one dataFrame named "nom" :

```
final_date = x.Date.iloc[-1]
for i in range(final_date):

    nom = "date_"+ '{}'.format(i)
    nom = DataFrame()
    nom = x[( x['Date'] == i )]
```

How should I do my python?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I’m not sure why could be gained from separate DataFrames like this. Why do you want to do with them?

Comment: For later on i wish to plot them.  I feel I have to do this because It is a Csv I work daily and every day i perform new experiments. So it would be for me to just add my new data with its date and then I do not have to worry to add a new csv.

Comment: But why do you think you need separate dataframes for that? You can just use a single dataframe with a date column, no? Sorry I might be missing something here

Comment: Yes Dear Cimbali, I have retexted my purpose. I do not need to separate the dataFrames, i just believe I have to do this, but It is how I figured out how to plot each set of data per each Date

Comment: In the loop you are setting same variable, so it will only have nom in the end

Comment: Yes, you are right, but If I try this:
for i in range(final_data):

   "data_"+ '{}'.format(i) = x1[( x1['Data'] == i )]
I get this error:
SyntaxError: cannot assign to operator

Comment: That is because it's not a variable, when you do it like this you are assigning value to a operator *+* string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic thing here is that you’re using a single name, `nom`, for all your dataframes. As soon as you build another dataframe, the previous one is replaced.

Now you could use instead a dictionary of dataframes:

```
final_date = x.Date.iloc[-1]
por_fecha = {}

for i in range(final_date + 1):
    por_fecha['date_{}'.format(i)] = x[( x['Date'] == i )]
```

This then returns the following dictionary:

```
{
'date_0':
  Empty DataFrame
  Columns: [P1, P2, Date]
  Index: [],
'date_1':
      P1  P2  Date
  0   1   2     1
  1   2   3     1,
'date_2':
      P1  P2  Date
  2   3   2     2
  3   4   3     2
}
```

An easier way to separate per date is to use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) (see also [this very interesting guide on groupby usage](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/user_guide/groupby.html))

Here we’ll use it in a slightly different way from the split-apply-combine pattern, as once you have defined the groups (by date value), you can access a dictionary with [`groupby(...).groups`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.groups.html):

```
>>> x.groupby('Date').groups
{1: [0, 1], 2: [2, 3]}
```

You see 2 first advantages on your method

1. this doesn’t use all numbers in the range 0..2 (or whatever date range you use), just the dates that exist
2. the values of the dictionary are the row indexes, so now you can use them in a loop as follows:

```
for date, idx in x.groupby('Date').groups.items():
    # Access only the subset with that date
    y = x.loc[idx]
    # Now plot y with date 
    y.plot(..., title='date {}'.format(date))
```

Comment: Thank you Dear Cimbali! I didn't know the existence of this dictionay of DataFrame... so much to learn!!

But I believe this groupby it is something incredible, thank you for showing this to me!

Comment: Dear Cimbali, I am trying your last code and I keep getting this error: TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object.  Any clue why it doesn't like this in x.groupby('Date').groups ?

Comment: Ah yes @LlorençMaciàCid it was missing a [`.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) − you can try it again I fixed the code.

Comment: Dear Cimbali, could you please tell me how I should I do if I want to print P1 vs P2 for each y.plot? I am trying  ""   y.plot(y.p1, y.p2, title='date {}'.format(data)) "" and it doesn't work

Comment: @LlorençMaciàCid Try `y.plot(x='p1', y='p2')`, see [the plot() documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) for more details

Comment: Dear @Cimbali,  Thank you for your patience in showing me how to python!
If I want to plot all of them in one same graph (now I see this creates as graphs as date i have)... any suggestion?